# Template interpretation for function in different header

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm having trouble writing a template for my wrapper class. I have a wrapper class called `Tmp` that implements `operator<<` for a few basic types. For every class (`Foo`) that needs this operator, it's implemented individually.

Now, I want to write a template that can process some iterable types if the operator is implemented. The template provided below works for basic types, but when it comes to classes implemented in different files, it doesn't work.

I understand that the compiler has no candidate to interpret this operator. Is there any other option to provide a candidate to the compiler other than implementing all classes in the same header file as the template?

MWE:

```cpp
// tmp.h
#include <iterator>

class Tmp {
  friend Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, int i);

  template<typename Iter>
  friend Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, std::pair<Iter, Iter> iter) {
    for (auto it = iter.first; it != iter.second; ++it) {
      os << *it;
    }
    return os;
  }
};

// tmp.cpp
Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, int i) {
  std::cout << i << '\n';
  return os;
}

// foo.h
class Foo {
  friend Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, const Foo&);
};

// foo.cpp
Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, const Foo&) {
  std::cout << "Foo\n";
  return os;
}

// main.cpp
int main() {

  std::vector vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  Tmp a;
  a << 0; 
  a << std::pair{vec.begin(), vec.end()};

  Foo foo;
  a << foo;
  std::vector foo_vec{Foo(), Foo(), Foo()};
  // a << foo_vec; //<- This line is not interpreted by template

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, const std::ranges::range auto& r) { return os << std::pair(std::begin(r), std::end(r)); }` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zo81W4j6f) (or similar SFINAE in C++17)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Two approaches

The simplest way to make this work is to create a `std::pair` of iterators for the `foo_vec`. This parallels what you did for the vector of `ints`.

```cpp
    // Approach 1. Create std:pair
    a << std::pair{ foo_vec.begin(), foo_vec.end() };
```

The second approach is to define another `operator<<` that takes a vector argument.

```cpp
    template<typename Container>
    friend Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, Container const& c) {
        os << std::make_pair(c.begin(), c.end());
        return os;
    }
```

That operator belongs in class Tmp:

```cpp
// tmp.h
#ifndef TMP_H
#define TMP_H
#include <iterator>

class Tmp {
    friend Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, int i);

    template<typename Iter>
    friend Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, std::pair<Iter, Iter> iter) {
        for (auto it = iter.first; it != iter.second; ++it) {
            os << *it;
        }
        return os;
    }

    template<typename Container>
    friend Tmp& operator<<(Tmp& os, Container const& c) {
        os << std::make_pair(c.begin(), c.end());
        return os;
    }
};
#endif
```

Here is a function `main` that demonstrates both approaches:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Foo.h"
#include "tmp.h"

int main() {

    std::vector vec{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Tmp a;
    a << 0;
    a << std::pair{ vec.begin(), vec.end() };

    Foo foo;
    a << foo;
    std::vector foo_vec{ Foo(), Foo(), Foo() };

    // Approach 1. Create std:pair
    std::cout << "Approach 1.\n";
    a << std::pair{ foo_vec.begin(), foo_vec.end() };

    // Approach 2. Define another operator<<
    std::cout << "Approach 2.\n";
    a << foo_vec;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output, showing "Foo" seven times, which equates to the vector being output twice, after the single Foo object has been output once

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
Foo
Approach 1.
Foo
Foo
Foo
Approach 2.
Foo
Foo
Foo
```